# Rescuing files from corrupted microSD

Tags: data-recovery, micro-sd-card

I was hoping some of you could advise me with recovering files (photos) from micro SD card that went corrupt. I know that in some cases nothing can be done, but I want to try everything before going to data-recovery company and pay huge amount of money.

The card is 7 days old Kingston micro SDXC 64GB UHS-I U3 and was used only in Canon digital camera. It worked fine first couple of days. Two days ago I took the card out of camera to review the photos taken that day on Win10 laptop (using included SD adapter), but shamefully didn't make a copy of them right away (around 80 pics). Then I took the card out without using "safely remove". I put the card back to the camera, everything was ok, pictures were still there and I continued shooting for another day. The next day the camera suddenly reported memory card error.

Now the PC isn't able to recognize the card at all. It beeps when connecting, but that's it. The card isn't visible in explorer nor Disk Manager. I connected the card using USB adapter this time to linux machine. It still doesn't work and is shown in "Disks" GUI utility as "Generic-SD/MMC" in /dev/sdb with "No medium" in volumes section. Fdisk doesn't list it. When I tried to do dd copy, i get "no media in /dev/sdb" error. The dmesg output when connecting the card is following:

```
[27291.152026] usb 2-5: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[27291.541450] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0119
[27291.541454] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[27291.541457] usb 2-5: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[27291.541459] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: Generic
[27291.541461] usb 2-5: SerialNumber: 20090815198100000
[27291.543000] usb-storage 2-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[27291.543102] scsi host20: usb-storage 2-5:1.0
[27292.541909] scsi 20:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- SD/MMC           1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[27292.542209] sd 20:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[27298.549150] sd 20:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I don't care about the card but I really do care about the photos. I am poor student so I'm willing to try everything before paying $100+ to some data recovery company. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: Did you try cleaning the contacts?  I usually use a pencil eraser.  Also I would use your local stores 30 day return policy to try a different card reader.

Comment: «Now the PC isn't able to recognize the card at all» Not quite, since you are showing that the device is recognized as `/dev/sdb`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

[PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) by cgsecurity will scan the card sector by sector and try to scrape the pictures off.

This program does not install, it operates in the folder you create.

The files indicated are the actual programs.
[image: Files inside ZIP]

```
PhotoRec 7.1-WIP, Data Recovery Utility, December 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org
                                                                                         PhotoRec is free software, and
comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
                                                                                       Select a media (use Arrow keys, then press Enter):
 Disk /dev/sda - 128 GB / 119 GiB (RO) - SAMSUNG SSD ######
 Disk /dev/sdb - 1024 GB / 953 GiB (RO) - Crucial_ ########
 Disk /dev/sdc - 250 GB / 232 GiB (RO) - Samsung SSD ########
 Disk /dev/sdd - 3000 GB / 2794 GiB (RO) - Hitachi ##########
>Disk /dev/sde - 120 GB / 111 GiB (RO) - Samsung SSD ##########
 Disk /dev/sdf - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB (RO) - ST2000DM ########
 Drive L: - 1127 MB / 1075 MiB (RO) - HL-DT-ST BD-RE  #######
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               >[Proceed ]  [  Quit  ]
                                                                                       Note:
Disk capacity must be correctly detected for a successful recovery.
If a disk listed above has incorrect size, check HD jumper settings, BIOS
detection, and install the latest OS patches and disk drivers.
```

Select **Whole disk**

```
PhotoRec 7.1-WIP, Data Recovery Utility, December 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org
                                                                                       Disk /dev/sde - 120 GB / 111 GiB (RO) - Samsung SSD 840 Series
                                                                                            Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
>     Unknown                  0   0  1 14593  80 63  234441648 [Whole disk]
  1 P Unknown                  0  32 33    57 126  5     921600 [Basic data partition]
  2 P EFI System              57 126  6    70  61 55     204800 [EFI system partition]
  3 P MS Reserved             70  61 56    72  71 63      32768 [Microsoft reserved par  4 P MS Data                 72  72  1 14593  66  1  233279488 [Basic data partition]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                >[ Search ]  [Options ]  [File Opt]  [  Quit  ]
                              Start file recovery


PhotoRec 7.1-WIP, Data Recovery Utility, December 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org
                                                                                            Unknown                  0   0  1 14593  80 63  234441648 [Whole disk]
                                                                                       To recover lost files, PhotoRec need to know the filesystem type where the
file were stored:
 [ ext2/ext3 ] ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem
>[ Other     ] FAT/NTFS/HFS+/ReiserFS/...
```

Then press **C** and wait possible a long time depending on the size of the device.

[image: It's go time]

The shown folder will appear, and the recovered files will go in there.  After 500 files it make a .2,.3,.4,.5 and etc folders.

[image: Results]

Documentation:

```
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk
```

Comment: That's just not going to work on a solid state drive; the clusters are not linear like a spinning disk.

Comment: @Tetsujin  The SD cards firmware hide the layer you describe.  This program operates at the level above that where all sectors are uniform.

Comment: @DavidPostill  I added instructions, and links.

Comment: @cybernard Much better :)

Comment: @DavidPostill  Does stackexchange have the ability to have a software catalog?  I don't mind writing instruction a few times, but this kind of question comes up 100's of times whether its hdd,ssd,sd, or etc.  We shouldn't have to copy and paste long answer over and over.  Even then copy and pasting doesn't work because the images still need uploading.  Also all this redundancy wastes tons of storage.  I should be able to lookup instructions that other have written, and link to them.  Where is the suggestion box around here?

Comment: @cybernard That is what marking as duplicate is for. If you don't think there is a duplicate then you can write a canonical question and answer.

Comment: @cybernard Bythe way there is already a duplicate question with an answer containing the same software recommendation [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/q/241817).

Comment: @DavidPostill  Take mhdd for instance, I searched there are 64 results.  Is there a better way than reading all 64, plus sub-answers to find the best available instructions?

Comment: @cybernard With more experience on [su] you will know the main list of questions which can be used as duplicate targets. I keep a list of around 20 or so which are common targets.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion using PhotoRec, but this isn't the main problem. I have successfully recovered files from damaged drives before using various software tools. The problem here is, that I don't see the drive as storage device. The dmesg shows it should be in /dev/sdb, but there are no volumes to recover files from... The question therefore is, how to make the PC see that partition, if possible.

Comment: By the way, people should stop suggesting to use Photorec **as the first attempt.** One should clearly want to try to access/reconstruct the file system with its full directory structure before resorting to a file carver that can only recover some files with specific structures (e.g. JPEG) without names. At least we should talk about Testdisk if we don't want to mention some more advanced tools.